# Browser support for Bootstrap 3 progress bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, progress-bar, browser-support

I am coding a MVC 5 view that needs to use a progress bar and am not sure the best way to do this. I am wanting to use the Bootstrap 3 progress bar at the following resource: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

On the resource page there is the following message:

```
Cross-browser compatibility
Progress bars use CSS3 transitions and animations to achieve some of their effects. These features are not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and below or older versions of Firefox. Opera 12 does not support animations.
```

My question is this: Should I use a different progress bar that does work on all browsers, or is it safe to say that the Bootstrap 3 progress bar should be used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The progress bars be less pretty, but still quite acceptable, in the browsers not supporting those features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress bar is supported in all browsers. Only that the striped gradient and CSS3 animation is not supported in older browsers. If you use a striped progress bar (`.progress-bar-striped`), older browsers (IE 9 and below) will show show it as a simple progress bar but it's dynamic width changing will work fine.

Take a look at these [browser statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp). All in all, it depends on whom you're building this website for - do maximum of your users have old browsers or new browsers?